# How to place brace on the right of a subset of aligned equations?

Tags: align, cases, braces

This question is essentially an extension of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/how-to-put-a-brace-on-the-right-not-left-to-group-cases) question about how to place right braces around cases.

I want to have three equations, all aligned, but I want **only** the latter two of the equations to be grouped by a right brace. I've tried things like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{aligned}
        \delta\psi&=i\beta\gamma^{5}\\
        \.
        \delta\sigma&=2\beta\pi\\
        \delta\pi&=-2\beta\sigma
        \right\rbrace
\end{aligned}
```

which obviously doesn't work, as the linked `\left\. ... \right\rbrace` can't work across the line break in  the aligned environment.

Essentially, I want something like this

[image]

but the right brace only connecting the lower two equations.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Uhm, I'm sure this has already popped out but right now I can find only [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446049/82917).

Comment: Check the first example in [`amsmath`'s user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf), sec. 3.7 "Alignment building blocks".

Comment: [math mode - Enumerate over mathmode items with partial curly brace - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582006/enumerate-over-mathmode-items-with-partial-curly-brace)

Comment: Oh, here is what I was looking for. Does [Side brace only some equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579883/82917) help?

Comment: @campa You're right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceArray}{r >{{}}c<{{}} l}
  \delta\psi   &=&  i\beta\gamma^{5} \\
  \delta\sigma &=&  2\beta\pi \\
  \delta\pi    &=& -2\beta\sigma
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix.{2-1}{3-3}\}
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

A couple LaTeX runs may be needed in order for the result to be final.

[image]

In this particular case, I find it more appealing to use left alignment for the first column: if you change the column specifications into

```
\begin{NiceArray}{l >{{}}c<{{}} l}
```

you get

[image]

What about text beside the brace? Here we need to better control the intercolumn spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceArray}{ @{} l @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l l @{} }
  \delta\psi   &=&  i\beta\gamma^{5} \\
  \delta\sigma &=&  2\beta\pi & \Block{2-1}{\text{whatever}}\\
  \delta\pi    &=& -2\beta\sigma
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix.{2-1}{3-3}\}
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great, really neat, and exactly what I'm looking for. Just to add - say I wanted to add text to the right of the brace. How would I go about that? I'm not sure I fully understand the syntax of the nicematrix package

Comment: @LC400 You want to add a block. I added the example.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the first row with a negative space (and compensate with a positive space elsewhere)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


align\vspace{\baselineskip}
\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
        \noalign{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
        \delta\psi&=i\beta\gamma^{5}\\
        \delta\sigma&=2\beta\pi\\
        \delta\pi&=-2\beta\sigma
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace  x
\]

\end{document}
```